# retrieving my seed phrase from id.json file

Tags: nfts, private-key

I have created an NFT collection on Solana network using the sugar machine.

I used a Solana wallet starting with "Gza..." to basically do everything and make all the necessary payments to activate my smart contract.

An id.json file was generated with an array of numbers that I believe represents my secret seed phrase.

Now I have forgotten the password to access my Gza wallet and can't find the 12/24 seed phrase to retrieve it...

I was wondering if there is anyway I could use the array of numbers from the id.json file to access my Gza wallet again...

any help would be appreciated

for clarification the array of numbers look like this: [1, 23, 55, 0, 2, 65, ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not share your array in id.json i.e private key with anyone.**

The array in id.json file represent the private key of your wallet.

Goto phantom or any Solana wallet.

1. Select add/connect wallet.
2. select the option of "Import Private Key".
3. And click import.

Your Gza... wallet will be accessible now.

Comment: thx it worked! I had to use the square brackets as well

Comment: Yeah, the whole content of the id.json even the square brackets should be copied.